# mysql server 8.0 keyring migration error at login

Tags: mysql, windows

I am using MySQL Server 8.0 on Windows 10. I followed [this tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html) to initialize.

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
λ mysqld --initialize
```

However, when I try to login with the temporary password, a keyring migration error shows up as below:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
λ mysqld -u root -p
Enter password: **********
mysqld: Can not perform keyring migration : Invalid --keyring-migration-source option.
2018-07-20T18:49:20.794197Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.11) starting as process 21312
2018-07-20T18:49:20.801815Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011084] [Server] Keyring migration failed.
2018-07-20T18:49:20.824651Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-07-20T18:49:20.829415Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.11)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I did not install any plugins relating to keyring by myself. Is there a way to skip or pass this keyring migration?

Answer (score 20):

1. After Installation on Windows. Look for the path to the installed folder.

   Example:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
   ```
2. Open cmd and `cd` to above path.
3. Type

   ```
   mysqld --initialize-insecure --console
   ```

   It will initialize the data folder manually without password to  root.

   For beginners I would suggest this option

   ```
   mysqld --initialize --console
   ```

   It will initialize the data folder manually with random password to  root.

   After this you might face an error that says:

   - Unable to create data folder. For this, try specifying the path to data like this:

     ```
     mysqld --initialize-insecure
            --basedir=specify your path/mysql/mysql
            --datadir=specify your path/mysql/data
     ```
   - Or data folder already exist. For this, go to that folder and delete the data folder.
   - Or, for now later versions, in data folder there is already a file exist named `my.ini`. For this, copy that file and paste it to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\` (you can do more changes here and specify the path to data and base dir)
4. Now you have successfully initialized without any password.
   Start the server.

   ```
   mysqld --console
   ```

   NOTE: You could define the path to system environment variable (search on Google on how to do it), after that you do not have to go this path every time.

   Now your server up and running.

   ```
   mysqld: ready for connections
   Version: '8.0.15'  socket: ''  port: 3306
   ```
5. Now use command:

   ```
   mysql -u root --skip-password
   ```

   and then

   ```
   mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
   ```

   This command to set root password.
6. For the next time use

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```

   And after that enter you `new_password`

Answer (score 10):

Try using `mysql -u root -p` instead of `mysqld - u root -p`

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could share the differences between the two

Comment: The difference is that the program sees "-u" root as a single argument to be parsed and "- u" as two completely different arguments. So the latter will fail

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, on Centos 7 it was just blocking mysql remote access and log was showing same issue "Keyring migration failure". After reloading the firewall it worked as it was since firewall had some changes applied.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on CentOS 8. I don't know what's the logic behind it but  `mysql -u root -p mysql` command work for me instead of `mysql -u root -p`.