# Keyring mirgration failure Fedora mySql

Tags: mysql, fedora

I've been working through MySQL but I've been having trouble entering my MySQL server to change certain properties. When I attempt to enter as root I get the following output:

```
//]$ sudo mysqld -u root -p
Enter password: 
mysqld: Can not perform keyring migration : Invalid --keyring-migration-source option.
2020-02-12T05:34:59.837715Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 64421
2020-02-12T05:34:59.839462Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011084] [Server] Keyring migration failed.
2020-02-12T05:34:59.839481Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-02-12T05:34:59.839559Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Can't figure out how to sort this out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51448958/mysql-server-8-0-keyring-migration-error-at-login) replacing my.ini with your my.cnf.

Answer (score 0):

`keyring-migration-source` exists in one of the configuration files.

`mysqld --help --verbose` will list which files are read at the top. Look in those and remove the line.

Also don't run mysqld as root. Its a security hazard and won't start. Use the `systemctl start mysql` that fedora provides.

Comment: I used the command you specified and got the order files as ```/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf```, however only the first one exists on my system and it does not contain keyring-migration-source.

Comment: Does it contain `include`/`includedir` referring to other files.

Comment: It does not, the only referenced files are those being defined as datadir, socket, log-error, and pid-file